# Install file dependent on processor architecture

Tags: windows, installation, arm, wix

We use Wix Windows Installer XML with bootstrapper, our target system is Windows 10.

On a Windows 10 running on an ARM system as virtualization, our software installs without problems, but crashes on certain actions because C++ runtime files for ARM architecture are missing.

Is it possible to create a condition in this setup for these runtime files to install only on ARM architecture without affecting other systems?

Do these files belong better in the MSI or in the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Many corporations roll out software using some kind of software change management tool like Microsoft SCCM. My experience is that they usually do not like all in one exe installers and rather want to control the installation of each component (msi).

So I would create a msi package for each architecture. You can then run the specific msi from the bundle with a condition on the "ProcessorArchitecture" property https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html.